# How to optimize the picker view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, optimization

I want my picker view can display 1 - 200. but I think it is too much memory, if I assign an Array in this view:

```
self.myLargeView = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1 unit", @"2 units", .... ..., @"199 units" @"200 units", nil]; //code skipped
```

How can I reduce the memory load in application? any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your picker view just to display an incremented number then you might use something like this:

```
#define kPickerValuesAmount 200

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPickerViewDataSource methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;   
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return kPickerValuesAmount;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i unit%@", (row + 1), (row == 0 ? @"" : @"s")];
}
```

Comment: It works fast enough even though each time the `titleForRow` is called new `NSString` object is allocated.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has to just pick a number from 1 to 200, why not use a UISlider instead?

Comment: I want the user can actually choose the number, I see the Apple date picker also can allow user to scroll many items.

Comment: If the row titles of the picker will be of the form "x unit(s)", you can generate the string in the titleForRow method instead of pre-allocating the array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

An array of 200 short NSStrings will not cause you any memory problems. It just takes up a few kilobytes.